# Hide a field on changing of Ticket Status in Vtiger

Tags: vtiger, vtigercrm

Hi I want to Hide Some Fields like Ticket solution when Ticket Status is changed to open. How to do it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding to the above comments , you can also copy Edit.js inside layouts > v7 > modules > Helpdesk > resources from some other layout. There you can write your own code inside **registerEventForPicklistDependencySetup** function. Dont forget to remove other unwanted functions.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using javascript for that task. Use a jquery selector to retrieve the value of ticketstatus and hide the container of the solution field if depending on the status.

Answer (score -1):

You can use jQuery to perform the task. In vTigerCRM the actual name of the ticket module is HelpDesk. So to change the detail view of ticket module you need to edit ***layouts/vlayout/modules/HelpDesk/DetailViewHeaderTitle.tpl***
file. For your reference, I am providing you with a sample.

[image]

Comment: Its not best practice to write JS functions in tpl. Create new Js file and add it in related views.